# CSV Files in Python (Sliding Window)

Tags: java, python, csv, dataset, pycharm

I am a beginner to Python, I need a help with manipulating csv files in Python.
I am trying to do sliding window mechanism for each row in dataset.

for an example if the dataset is this

```
timestamp | temperature | windspeed
965068200   9.61883  60.262   
965069100   9.47203  60.1664 
965070000   9.31125  60.0145   
965070900   9.13649  59.8064
```

and if user specified window size is 3,the result should be something like

```
timestamp | temperature-2 | temperature-1 |temperature-0 | windspeed-2 | windspeed-1 | windspeed-0
965070000   9.61883 9.47203 9.31125 60.262 60.1664 60.0145
965070900   9.47203 9.31125 9.13649 60.1664 60.0145 59.8064
```

I could do this by using List of ObjectsArray in Java.Reading CSV and generate new CSV which it contains transformed dataset.
Here is the code 
http://pastebin.com/cQnTBg8d #researh

I need to do this in Python , please help me to solve this.

*Thank you*

Comment: Have you had a look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, yet?

Comment: this actually does not look like actual csv so it could be easier to just use string methods.

Comment: is your csv big ? can it be held in memory ?

Comment: Thanks for asking @FloranGmehlin, Here is the link for CSV http://www.sharecsv.com/s/f193721233146a16a1032c42d8a33517/trainerDataCSV.csv file contains actually 961 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer assumes you are using Python 3.x - for Python 2.x some changes are required (some obvious places are commented)**

For the data format in the question, this could be a starting point in Python:

```
import collections

def slide(infile,outfile,window_size):
    queue=collections.deque(maxlen=window_size)
    line=infile.readline()
    headers=[s.strip() for s in line.split("|")]
    row=[headers[0]]
    for h in headers[1:]
        for i in reversed(range(window_size)):
            row.append("%s-%i"%(h,i))
    outfile.write(" | ".join(row))
    outfile.write("\n")
    for line in infile:
        queue.append(line.split())
        if len(queue)==window_size:
            row=[queue[-1][0]]
            for j in range(1,len(headers)):
                for old in queue:
                    row.append(old[j])
            outfile.write("\t".join(row))
            outfile.write("\n")

ws=3
with open("infile.csv","r") as inf:
    with open("outfile.csv","w") as outf:
        slide(inf,outf,ws)
```

actually this code is all about using a queue to keep the input rows for the window and not more - everything else is text-to-list-to-text.

With actual csv-data (see comment)

```
import csv
import collections

def slide(infile,outfile,window_size):
    r=csv.reader(infile)
    w=csv.writer(outfile)
    queue=collections.deque(maxlen=window_size)
    headers=next(r) # r.next() on python 2
    l=[headers[0]]
    for h in headers[1:]
        for i in reversed(range(window_size)):
            l.append("%s-%i"%(h,i))
    w.writerow(l)
    hrange=range(1,len(headers))
    for row in r:
        queue.append(row)
        if len(queue)==window_size:
            l=[queue[-1][0]]
            for j in hrange:
                for old in queue:
                    l.append(old[j])
            w.writerow(l)

ws=3
with open("infile.csv","r") as inf: # rb and no newline param on python 2
    with open("outfile.csv","w") as outf: # wb and no newline param on python 2
        slide(inf,outf,ws)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support @janbrohl , encounted error in this line, I guess.    headers=[s.strip() for s in infile.readline().strip().strip("*").split("|")].            and please mention question is edited now.

Comment: changed accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your effort @janbrohl , I am not able to compile because of some errors. could you able to fix this too please ? https://i.imgsafe.org/14dea045e4.png

Comment: sorry, program is running and no csv file is generated.  http://www.sharecsv.com/s/f193721233146a16a1032c42d8a33517/trainerDataCSV.csv - input csv                            https://i.imgsafe.org/1537fe2714.png - IDE                                            Your help would be more valuable.

Comment: would have been great if you posted cvs-data right in the question - my answer is for the format of the example datasets in your question

Comment: sorry for the mistake , the reason I put the question like that is for making easy to understand.The actual dataset is the one I shared just above.please do accept this. Hope you could able to help me on this.

Comment: see extended answer

Comment: as stated in my comment in the source code - it is made for python 3.x and must be edited for python 2.x. Just apply these changes (eg `open("infile.csv","rb")`) - put at least some effort of your own in it. There is a python tutorial at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I could able generate the csv as expected by removing newline=''.Now It's working. Thank you so much . Now my problem is what if I don't need to split particular columns , can we do that ?

Comment: See the tutorial + [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) - if you want me to invest more time on this, hire me.